# Creating functions and concatenate registers values

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

I am new to assembly and need some help creating a function.  I have a little piece of code done, but need a nudge to complete.  The function I need (`ReadHexByte`) will read from the keyboard input a byte (two digits 0-9) and store it in AL register.  Ultimately, the first digit entered will be set as the most significant nibble of AL and the second digit entered will be set as the least significant nibble of AL.  I can get to a point where the first digit is stored in DH and second digit is in DL.

Example of problem: If user inputs 9 and then 4, this would be the byte 94h.  AL would then store 94h

```
.data
    charIn1 BYTE ?
    charIn2 BYTE ? 

.code
main proc
    call ReadChar ;user enters 9
    mov dh, al ;move 39h to dh
    sub dh, 30h ;dh set to 09h
    call ReadChar ;user enters 4
    mov dl, al ; move 34h to dl
    sub dl, 30h ;dl set to 04h
```

1. How do I combine DH (09) and DL (04) into AL?
2. How do I create a function that performs this?

Comment: Pseudocode would be of course  `AL = (DH << 4) | DL`. Is that enough of a nudge for you?

Comment: This is the reverse question of your earlier one ([Storing most significant/least significant nibble in registers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52357270)), about how to unpack, right?  If you want to take advantage of partial-register stuff, `shl dl, 4` / `shl dx,4` should pack both nibbles into DH.  (And then you don't need `sub` to remove the high bits first)